# Como hacer build de una app React Native para ios sin cuenta de apple developer

Tags: reactjs, ios, react-native, app, build

Estoy desarrollando una app en react native, usando expo hago el build para android pero cuando intento hacerlo para ios me aparece un error por que no estoy registrado en apple developer, entiendo que para subir la app a app store si o si necesito esa cuenta pero solo necesito hacer el build. Se que con ionic y capacitor se puede hacer el build gratis pero necesito hacerlo con react native. Alguien sabe si se puede?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]